# Laravel 5.4 pluck an entire list

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel model controller I have this:
      public function guestInfo($id)

```
{
    $guests = Person::where('id', $id)
              ->with('languages')
              ->get();

    return view('layouts.visitor', ['guests' => $guests]);
}
```

in my blade file I have this:

```
        @foreach ($guests as $guest)
some html stuff in here
{!! Form::select('name', $guest->languages->pluck('name')->all(), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
more html
@endforeach
```

Person is a model to a db table "persons" and "languages" is a relative model "belongs to" Person.

In my languages table I have different rows for languages: "english, spanish, etc" each is in it's own row with it's own id.
My goal is to get all the languages to show up.  However currently with the above code I only get one language to show up.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you do a `dd($guest->languages);` in your `Controller`, do you get an array with more than a single language?

Answer (score 1):

your code will retrieve only that languages which associated with persons. if you want to show all languages, just retrieve them as `id => name` pairs and pass to your view.

```
 $guests = Person::where('id', $id)->get();
 $languagess = Language::pluck('name', 'id);
```

and then do `foreach` with `$languages`

```
@foreach ($languages as $key => $val)

  {!! Form::select('name', $key, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

@endforeach
```

Comment: this causes error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() @devnull Ψ

Comment: did you dump ` $languages` ? you should first check array if its not empty and only then iterate through it

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it like this with some help from @devnull Ψ.  Not exactly as he suggested but it gave me some direction.

Controller:

```
public function guestInfo($id)
{
    $guests = Person::where('id', $id)
              ->with('languages')
              ->get();

    $languages = Language::pluck('name')->toArray();

    return view('layouts.visitor', ['guests' => $guests, 'languages' => $languages]);
}
```

Then in my blade:

```
{!! Form::select('name', $languages, 'name', ['placeholder' => '<select>','class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```